# JtaTransaction with Resin

Tags: spring, hibernate, jta, resin, xa

I use JtaTransactionManager of Resin to manage jta transaction in Resin Server,following is spring config for transactionManager.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

following is datasource config.

```
<bean id="dataSourceFinance" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName"><value>${hibernate.connection.driver_class}</value></property>
    <property name="url"><value>${hibernate.connection.finance.url}</value></property>
    <property name="username"><value>${hibernate.connection.finance.username}</value></property>
    <property name="password"><value>${hibernate.connection.finance.password}</value></property>
</bean>
```

1. I wonder why the common connection also supports two phase commit since this config can work well.
2. When i have to replace the connection of dbcp with xa connection.
3. Whether the connection of dbcp supports two phase commit.

Comment: I have a mistake on this quesion that it actually doesn't work.

Comment: I have a mistake on this quesion that it actually doesn't work in global transaction.It looks well because its high level isolation "ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE" and session.flush() is invoked in triggerBeforeCommit method of TransactionSynchronizationUtils rather than in global transaction committed.